# Android App Unresponsive

Tags: android, debugging

The UI thread of my app locks up at indeterminate and un-reproduceable times. Can anyone suggest a tool or a mindset that I should use to debug this problem? I can't really predict when it happens, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the code itself.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it in the eclipse debugger and when it's hung/paused/locked up quickly break into the app and inspect the main thread. More often then not you'll be able to see which long running operation is being run on the main thread.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that the default Eclipse debugger worked with Android development. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

look for the tool called traceview.

Comment: I've tried using it but the problem is that when the app locks up, it can't call the "endTrace" method, and thus the trace is completed improperly and does not write any data.